# How do you have the API recognize the "Template ID" on DOCUSIGN. I am putting the template but its blank

Tags: api, docusignapi, crm

I have the API built in my custom CRM and its working fine but the issue is that the application is being sent out blank. We currently have it were we already have the necessary fields that will guide the client through the process instead of them having to drag and drop certain items.

Comment: Can you provide an API log of your attempt? https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're defining the template ID correctly in the call, the next most likely cause of failure is that your Recipients aren't being correctly assigned to the Template Roles.

Can you confirm the Role Names in your template match what you're assigning in the API call?

Comment: Drew ill ask my developer now exactly whats going on so I can technically explain. I wish I can upload a picture to show you.